# Sum of two group values inside foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter, foreach

I am having nested foreach like,

```
 foreach ($student_due_fee as $key => $fee) {

     foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_key => $fee_value) {

     ?>

        <tr>

          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->name; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->fee_groups_id; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->parent_fee_groups_id; ?></td>
          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->total_amount ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->group_fee_type ?> </td>
          <td> <?php echo $fee_value->group_fee_amount ?> </td>

      </tr>
   <?php
     }
 }
?>
```

And the result table looks like,

```
   group_name    group_id    parent_group_id     amount   group_type

     One           69             0               3300   I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES;
     Two           70             0               450    CO - SCHOLASTICS; BOOKS; 
    Three          71            69              -100    CONCESSION
```

And the `print_r($fee_value)` gives the following,

```
    stdClass Object ( [id] => 2 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 15 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-19 11:36:57 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 74 [group_fee_type] => I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES; SPORTS FEES [group_fee_amount] => 1000.00; 2000.00; 300.00 [amount] => 1000.00 [total_amount] => 3300.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 69 [parent_fee_groups_id] => 0 [name] => Ist Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 1 [code] => ISEMTUTION [type] => I SEM TUTION FEES [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

    stdClass Object ( [id] => 48 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 16 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-19 11:37:36 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 77 [group_fee_type] => MAGAZINE, PHOTOS,BAG, ID etc ; CO - SCHOLASTICS; BOOKS, NOTEBOOKS, UNIFORM [group_fee_amount] => 200.00; 150.00; 100.00 [amount] => 200.00 [total_amount] => 450.00 [due_date] => 2018-04-24 [fee_groups_id] => 70 [parent_fee_groups_id] => 0 [name] => IInd Term - LKG [feetype_id] => 7 [code] => MAGAZINE [type] => MAGAZINE, PHOTOS,BAG, ID etc [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 ) 

    stdClass Object ( [id] => 93 [student_session_id] => 278 [fee_session_group_id] => 20 [is_active] => no [created_at] => 2018-04-19 11:40:36 [fee_groups_feetype_id] => 84 [group_fee_type] => CONCESSION [group_fee_amount] => -100.00 [amount] => -100.00 [total_amount] => -100.00 [due_date] => 1970-01-01 [fee_groups_id] => 71 [parent_fee_groups_id] => 69 [name] => DISCOUNT [feetype_id] => 15 [code] => CONCESSION [type] => CONCESSION [student_fees_deposite_id] => 0 [amount_detail] => 0 )
```

Here i am in the need of sum of two groups if there is a matching with group id and parent group id, and my desired result is like,

```
   group_name    group_id    parent_group_id     amount   group_type

     One           69             0               3200   I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES; CONCESSION
     Two           70             0               450    CO - SCHOLASTICS; BOOKS;
```

If parent group id (69) matches with fee group id (69), then they will combine as single group and i need to sum up the amount of both row and display it as one. Here the amount in three needs to get sum up with the amount in group one as there is a match with parent group.

Inside foreach i have tried with if like,

```
foreach ($student_due_fee as $key => $fee) {

     foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_key => $fee_value) {

    if ($fee_value->parent_fee_groups_id == $fee_value->fee_groups_id) {
         echo "string";
       }

    }
 }
?>
```

But it doesn't help me. Any help that gives me a solution as like the table i have mentioned would me more appreciable..

Comment: Where do you set `$group_id`?

Comment: $group_id  should be like $fee_value->group_id in if condition

Comment: @PauloHgo,  It is ```$fee_value->fee_groups_id``` , changed in question also.

Comment: another alternative also is to sum it using the query (db layer) also, so that you don't need to sum it in PHP layer

Comment: @Ghost, I have already sum up the types inside the group in MySQL, you could see there is a type like "I SEM TUTION FEES; II SEM TUTION FEES;" which has each amount and that sum is the "3300" i have made already a group by and sum.. And also there is lot of joins inside the query and it is too mess and hence seeking for a help in php way.

Comment: if thats the case just use the `$fee_value->fee_groups_id`. initialize it to zero first `if not yet set ($container[$fee_groups_id]) then $container[$fee_groups_id] = 0`, then put it inside an array `$container[$fee_groups_id] += $total_amount `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated:

```
foreach ($student_due_fee as $key => $fee) {

     foreach ($fee->fees as $fee_key => $fee_value) {

        $results[] = array(

              'group_name'      => $fee_value->name,
              'group_id'        => $fee_value->fee_groups_id,
              'parent_group_id' => $fee_value->parent_fee_groups_id,
              'amount'          => $fee_value->total_amount,
              'group_type'      => $fee_value->group_fee_type,
              'group_amount'    => $fee_value->group_fee_amount

          );

     }
 }


 for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++){

   for($j = 0; $j < count($results); $j++){

     if($results[$i]['group_id'] == $results[$j]['parent_group_id']){

           $results[$i]['amount'] += $results[$j]['amount'];
           $results[$i]['group_type'] .=  ' ' . $results[$j]['group_type'];
           $rowsToBeDeleted[] = $j;

     }

   }

 }


 foreach($rowsToBeDeleted as $key=>$value){

 unset($results[$value]);

 }


echo 
'<table>

  <tr>

    <th>Group Name</th>
    <th>Group ID</th>
    <th>Parent Group ID</th>
    <th>Amount</th>
    <th>Group Type</th>
    <th>Group Amount</th>



  </tr>';

foreach($results as $key){

  echo 
    '<tr>

      <td>' . $key['group_name'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_id'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['parent_group_id'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['amount'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_type'] . '</td>' .
      '<td>' . $key['group_amount'] . '</td>' .

  '</tr>';

}

echo 
'</table>';
```

Comment: I need to make everything from group three into the group one. The amount needs to sum and the fee type of concession needs to get concatenated with the first group types. And the result needs to be like the desired result mentioned in question.

Comment: @Mani Raj  Please see updated answer, I missed the fact that you wanted the group_type concatenated in.

Comment: Thanks for your help but here amount is getting total but the group is not getting concatenated to the one. As mentioned earlier as expected result, the fee type concession in group three needs to get concatenated to the fee group one..

Comment: Are you using my most recent updated code.. It should be doing that

Comment: Yes i am using your recent code only and its making the sum and showing amount as "3200" but the Concession not get into fee type of group one.. I am sure that i am using your updated code only.. Look my desired result and i am in the need of same. Once again your good help is appreciable..

Comment: is this in the 2nd loop:  $results[$i]['group_type'] .=  ' ' . $results[$j]['group_type'];

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169381/discussion-between-joseph-j-and-mani-raj).

Comment: Thanks it helped me a lot.